# How do you find the conditional PDF of X, if it is known that X was in a certain interval?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given random variable X with PDF: $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}sin(x)$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$

If we know that $X\in(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{2\pi}{3}]$

What is the conditional probability density function of X? 
$f(x|X\in(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{2\pi}{3}])=?$

Answer (score 0):

For $x\leq \pi/3$ and $x\geq 2\pi/3,$ $F(x|X\in(\pi/3, 2\pi/3])$ equals $0$ and $1$ respectively. If $x\in (\pi/3, 2\pi/3),$ we have
$$P(X\leq x| X\in (\pi/3, 2\pi/3]) = \frac{P(X\leq x, X\in (\pi/3, 2\pi/3])}{P(X\in (\pi/3, 2\pi/3])} = \frac{P(X\in (\pi/3, x])}{P(X\in (\pi/3, 2\pi/3])}.$$

Can you express the RHS in terms of $F_X$?

Comment: How is $F(x|X\in(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{2\pi}{3}]$ equal to 0 and 1?
$\frac{1}{2}sin(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{1}{2}sin(\frac{2\pi}{3}) = 0.433...$

Comment: If $x\leq \pi/3$, then $X\in (\pi/3, 2\pi/3]$ implies that we do not have $X\leq x.$ Hence, $F(x|X\in(\pi/3, 2\pi/3]) = P(X\leq x| X\in(\pi/3, 2\pi/3]) = 0.$

Comment: The confusion is that your $F_X$ is a *probability density function*, rather than the CDF capital lettering usually denotes. So:  $$\begin{align}\mathsf P\big(X\in(\pi/3..2\pi/3]\big) &=\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}\tfrac 12\sin(x)~\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\dfrac 12\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh, I see. My bad. In that case, $F_X$ should be replaced by the cdf of $X$ in my answer. The rest is the same, just differentiate to get the pdf.

Comment: Sorry, would you be able to show me how to do that? I'm not too sure as to what you mean. I have updated the question to be $f_X$ instead of $F_X$

Comment: A probability density function is the derivative of the cummulative probability function for a continuous random variable, so:$$\begin{align}f_{X\mid X\in(a:b]}(x)&=\dfrac{\mathrm d ~\mathsf P(X\leq x\mid X\in(a:b])}{\mathrm d x\qquad}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{f_X(x)}{\mathsf P(X\in(a:b])}~\cdot\mathbf 1_{x\in(a:b]}\end{align}$$